# flash error 1061: call to a possibly undefined method addlistener through a reference with static type class

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I get the error :

> flash error 1061: call to a possibly undefined method addlistener
>   through a reference with static type class

I'm new at this so I'm not sure what the problems is. The idea is that when user doesn't move the mouse in scene 1, the animation would go and play scene A (that one is before scene 1).

Code below is what I've tried :

```
trace("STARTING");
var nStartTime: Number;
var nTimeout: Number = 10;
var nTimerInterval: Number;
var bTiming: Boolean;

nTimerInterval = setInterval(runTimer, 50);

var oMouseListener:Object = new Object();

oMouseListener.onMouseMove = function() 
{
    trace("THERE IS MOUSE ACTIVITY");
    nStartTime = getTimer();
    bTiming = true;
};

Mouse.addListener(oMouseListener);

function runTimer(): void
{
    if (bTiming) 
    {
        var timePassed = getTimer()-nStartTime;
        trace(timePassed/1000);
        if (timePassed/1000> nTimeout) 
        {
            gotoAndPlay("1, Scene `enter code here`a");
            trace("USER HAS BEEN INACTIVE FOR "+nTimeout+" SECONDS");
            bTiming = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many solutions available on google. Check this **[tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3events/)** for how to do an **addEventListener**. Also read this **[tutorial](https://ughzoid.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/detect-mouse-inactivity-in-actionscript-3-0/)** for a good way of detecting if mouse is idle for X amount. PS: I did not downvote but your code format was terrible, also what were you thinking when you did this line `var oMouseListener:Object = new Object();` later followed by `Mouse.addListener(oMouseListener);`??

Comment: Also a tip... Keep **all your code in one frame** and put your frames content (select frames in timeline and cut/paste) inside a container (MovieClip) and use something like `containerMC.gotoAndPlay( etc etc);`. Travel through that MC's frames instead of just making the entire stage itself move. You'll have less `variables` issues later on.

Comment: I learned to use flash 3 days ago , I copy a code for a tutorial I don't really understand the codes , but I supposed that  the code I saw in internet could work

Comment: by the way thanks i'm going to see the tutorials

Comment: @Vanessa That code is a valid **ActionScript 2** code (except the `void` which should be `Void`). You have compiled it as ActionScript 3 code and that's why it is not working.